# actionHero.js Set Http Header

Tags: proxy, http-headers, actionhero

I want to know if there is a way to Set the Http.Header in actionHero.js:
in our server we are working with actionHero.js and Go. I need to send on the "Header" two domain name "client domain & mine(actionHero Service)" to the Go service. 
or if there is any other way to do it on the Proxy server

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you mean the response header to the client, in your actions or initializers you can do:

`data.connection.rawConnection.responseHeaders.push(['x-my-header', 'abc123'])`

If you want to set persistent headers that the server responds to all requests with, you can set those in `api.config.servers.web.httpHeaders`